# Asking a question that is already has an answer, but for a different question

Tags: discussion, questions

I basically wanted to ask if this C code is valid:

```
    printf("%u\n", (unsigned int) INT_MAX + 1);
```

I noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2085031/1270789) to a different question, but the first paragraph is the exact answer to my question. On the other hand, that other question generates a compiler warning on `gcc` and is about mixing types in a comparison, whereas in my example is about whether or not there is an overflow.

Furthermore, earlier today I flagged someone else who posted a similar type of question, but added extra text to the "duplicate" comment to say that the question wasn't a duplicate, but already had an answer.

Ideally, I'd like my question posted to help other people searching on similar keywords, but with a pointer to the duplicate, but I feel that if I post I'll be voted down and have my question deleted.

What is the correct protocol for this situation?

Comment: So question 1 asks for the answer to A and gets an answer that works for A and B. Question 2 asks for an answer to B. Is question 2 a duplicate even though it is not asking for an answer to A? 

I came into this problem when asking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054654/delete-multiple-columns-by-reference-using-reverse-selection-in-data-table)  and don't know if I should delete it or not. Technically, folks looking for an answer to B wouldn't find it unless they looked for an answer to A.